# How can I save images to iphone directory and retrieve it?

Tags: iphone

I want to save image in iphone album and retrieve them on particular index, how can I?

I have to save profile of many people, along with their images, so how can I access such concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not save images in iPhone album if they're your application related only.

The better way is to create directory in your application documents directory and store them there. Or even better, do use CoreData and transient property to store image on your disk to keep your data well organized.

Comment: I'd go with the store them in your own directory approach. Create a folder called something like 'cachedPhotos' and then generate a suitable unique filename from some key you have (maybe the userid or similar). If you are going to have thousands of them, you may want to consider splitting them up into sub-folders based on some hashing function of the userid. Make sure you implement a mechanism for controlling the disk space used, perhaps LRU or similar. I wouldn't bother with the complexity of coredata / sqlite just for an image cache.

Comment: Yes, if your project doesn't use CoreData, do not use CoreData for just images. It can help a lot if you have some templates, but it can confuse you too if you didn't touch CoreData yet.

Answer (score 1):

you also have choice to save the image in sqlite3 database and retrieve it when needed.

Comment: Don't do this unless you have small images and just few of them.

Comment: @Chiefly Izzy :Yes i don't recommend for large images BUT He is talking abt profile image.

Comment: Yes, he is, but even profile image can be quite big. It was just warning, that this is not recommended for big images and huge number of images. No offense ;-)

Comment: YES,I know @Chiefly Izzy: your are right but It's just an approach and should be used with small images and can be resized before storing in database :)

Comment: @Jhaliya, but I have hundreds of profiles, not single one,,,,,

Comment: @Veer :What are there expected size ?